# Issue in layout go upper side after keyboard open for edit text android

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, android-softkeyboard

Hello friends i have below layout

[image]

layour code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/bussi_bg" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_tt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_buss_login"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_15"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txt_visit_site"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_tt"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Convenient Access"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Go beyond Properties and Transaction management"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_buss"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your bussiness email"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoEnterAction"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="#A6A6A6"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_white_cursor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_15" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_get_started"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Get started"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_18"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_visit_site"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="ABC."
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_12"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file set code  like below

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ActivityA"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|stateVisible" />
```

When i focus edittext in phone my screen look like below

[image]

See login button logo cut due to edittext open but i want to stay remain as it is in its place after keyboard open so any idea how can i solve this problem ?your all suggestion are appreciable

Answer (score 4):

Set Window SoftInput Mode property to adjustPan and adjustResize in manifest file.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Call inside your `Activity`:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change gravity of relative layout containing "Convenient access" from center to center_horizontal. Also keep marginTop some value according to your requirement. Changed code shown below,

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/txt_visit_site"
android:layout_below="@+id/rel_tt"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:text="Convenient Access"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Please let me know whether your problem rectified or not.

Comment: Above two answers are working properly. Good answers Goblin and kushan11